# Pseudocode for BFS(from The Algorithm Design, 2nd Ed.) confusion?

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

I need help with BFS pseudocode from The Algorithm Design Manual 2nd Edition, Skiena.

Line that says `process vertex u as desired`
and same thing but with edge(s) `process edge (u, v) as desired`
How should I write these lines in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you try to achieve with the algorithm. Those locations are the place where you put code which actually does something application specific.

If you're writing just a test-implementation you can insert console outputs there to see in which order the vertices/edges are processed

Comment: Well, actually I want to translate pseudocode from the book to C++ code, but I will insert console outputs for now. Thanks.